# Bootstrap 4 beta custom checkbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Is there any way to show `.invalid-feedback` with `.custom-checkbox`? After beta update `.has-danger` class not available anymore.

```
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input is-invalid" required>
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">Check this custom checkbox</span>
    <span class="invalid-feedback">
        <strong>Error!</strong>
   </span>
</label>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3kx7ad0m/1/)

Comment: https://hackerthemes.com/bootstrap-cheatsheet/#has-danger

Comment: @mlegg it's old version - 4.0.0-alpha.6. I asking for beta realise

Comment: sorry, I posted the wrong link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: @mlegg Sorry. No examples in documentation for custom checkboxes, that's why i asking. Even for regular...

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem.